# Remove self from observableArray in Knockout?

Tags: knockout.js

Take this example:

```
var ViewModel = function(data)
{
    this.users = ko.mapping.fromJS(data,
        {
            create: opts => new UserModel(opts.data),
        });
}


var UserModel = function(data)
{
    ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, this);

    this.remove = function(user)
    {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'DELETE',
            url: API+'user',
            data: ko.mapping.toJSON(this),
            contentType: 'application/json',
            context: this,
            success: function(data)
            {
                // How to remove from array?
                this.parent.users.remove(this); // ?
            },
        });
    };
}

<a href="javascript:void(0)" data-bind="click: remove">Remove</a>
```

Is there a way to remove "myself" from the array I'm in when the success handler is called?

Or is the only way to move the remove method up to the parent, and bind it like below?

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)"
    data-bind="click: $parent.remove.bind($parent, $data)>Remove</a>
```

---

**Note:** I've looked at similar questions here, but couldn't find any that gave a clear answer on this exact scenario. When combined with an ajax request (i.e. it shouldn't be removed until success), can it be done, and if not, how *should* it be done?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if you already tried this approach but try passing the `ViewModel` into UserModel. It's not ideal but there is no way for you to get the reference of `users` collection inside the `ajax call` without passing the `ViewModel` inside.

```
var ViewModel = function(data)
{
    var self = this;
    this.users = ko.mapping.fromJS(data,
    {
        create: opts => new UserModel(opts.data, self),
    });
}

var UserModel = function(data, parentContext)
{
    ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, this);
    var self = this;

    this.remove = function(user)
    {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'DELETE',
            url: API+'user',
            data: ko.mapping.toJSON(this),
            contentType: 'application/json',
            context: this,
            success: function(data)
            {
                parentContext.users.remove(this);

                // or
                // parentContext.users.remove(self);                  

                // or 
                // parentContext.users.remove(function(user) 
                // { 
                //   return user.Id == self.Id;
                // }); 
            },
        });
    };
}
```

Comment: I get an error saying `parent` is not defined on this/self. *Should* it be available on `this` in theory?

Comment: what sample did you try? first approach? or the validation approach?

Comment: I didn't realize that your users collection came from ViewModel. Hang on I'll update it. Or simply pass the viewModel into UserModel. It's not ideal but just for testing purpose to see what well happen.

Comment: Passing the ViewModel to the UserModel is something that would probably work fine, but that's what I'm trying to avoid. Basically, I'm looking for some sort of "destroy self" method, that the parent could pick up on, preferably built-in already, to "hey, one of my items just killed itself, I should remove it from my list"

Comment: If that's the case try to subscribe to userModel obserbable property or computed or callback to viewModel.

Comment: Not sure if there's a built that will automatically remove from observableArray once object kill himself

Comment: Ok, guess maybe the answer might be *no* then, unless someone else has some light the shed on this (or a super clever workaround, hehe).

Answer (score 0):

1. The simplest solution is to move your remove function from the UserModel up to the ViewModel, and change the click binding to `click: $parent.remove`. The current item still gets passed into the function and you have access to the collection as well.

   [jsFiddle-1](https://jsfiddle.net/jlspake/5by1Lvvo/)
2. If for some reason the remove function has to be on the UserModel then I would probably set up an event handler hack by using an observable property, and have the parent ViewModel subscribe to notifications on that property. You'd have to adjust your ko.mapping create function to add the subscription for each UserModel.

   [jsFIddle-2](https://jsfiddle.net/jlspake/4vco28x6/)

Comment: @svish Accidentally posted the wrong fiddle at first. The link for fiddle 1 should be the correct code now.